# Dymo LW550 only responds to version command

Tags: embedded-linux, cups, dymo

I am working on medical instrument that runs an embedded linux.  The instrument currently prints to LW450 printers (discontinued) using the cups driver to print to a file and then copying the file to /dev/lp0.  When I plug in the newer LW550, the OS recognizes the USB device class and creates /dev/lp0.  But when I send the commands listed [here](https://developers.dymo.com) under "Driver Only Package" the printer only responds to the version command .

I'm hoping someone else has encountered this and has an idea on what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Dymo and received an answer to this problem.  Dymo provided a technical reference document with the latest protocol changes.  The new protocol includes a lock feature where a user can "lock" the printer so that other users will know it is in use.  While locked, the printer will not respond to commands other than version and status.  I was unable to get the status command to work previously because the status command now includes a 3rd byte to request the lock be set or cleared.